# React Material UI Select conditional rendering shows value as out of range

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, conditional-statements, menuitem

The use case is creating an order that has multiple order lines. I have two lists of Products: `Preferred` and `All`. Every item in `Preferred` is in `All`. I have a boolean state variable `ShowPreferredProducts` to toggle between which list is passed in the `Select` to render the `MenuItem` list.

```
<Select
  label="itemNumber"
  {(showPreferredProducts ? preferredProducts : allProducts) 
    .map((product, idx) => (
      <Mui.MenuItem
        key={`${product.itemNumber}_${idx}`}
        value={product.itemNumber}
        />
          {product.itemName}
      </Mui.MenuItem>
      ))}
      <ListSubheader sx={{ position: 'sticky', bottom: '0' }}>
        <Mui.Box sx={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}>
          <Mui.Button
            sx={{ pointerEvents: 'all' }}
            onClick={(event) => {
              setShowPreferredProducts((prev) => !prev);
              }}>
                {showPreferredProducts ? 'Show Preferred Products' : 'Show All Products'}
           </Mui.Button>
         </Mui.Box>
       </ListSubheader>
     </Select>
```

When the button is clicked, we re-render the `MenuItem` list in the `Select`. When a user selects a product that is in `All`, but not in `Preferred`, while `showPreferredProducts` is true, any products in list `All` now display as empty (as it cannot find the value in the currently rendered list).

The user wants to always see the `Preferred` list first (at least for new order lines). A hacky way to keep all items being displayed is to force `showPreferredProducts` to `false` in an `onClose` and it to `true` in an `onOpen`. This does not fix the display issue while order lines are being edited, but it does keep the display looking as it should when the order is not being updated.

What is the preferred way of solving this? It "works", but it feels like there is a better way.

Edit:

Found a working solution. There may be a better way but this works and does not cause warnings and correctly allows for searching as well.

Since `preferredProducts` is a subset of `allProducts`, we render `allProducts` and at the `MenuItem` level we choose to display or not based on some functional programming.

```
// ensure product's item number and the MenuItem's 
// item number is equal since this is done on the `MenuItem` level.
const isProductInSearchValue = (product: Product, itemNumber: string) =>
product.itemNumber === itemNumber &&
(!productSearchValue ?? product.SomeValueToSearch.includes(productSearchValue);

// pick a list to filter from based on showPreferredProducts
const isItemVisibleInProductList = (itemNumber: string) =>
  (showPreferredProducts && preferredProducts.some((prod) => isProductInSearchValue(prod, itemNumber))) || 
  (!showPreferredProducts && allProducts.some((prod) => isProductInSearchValue(prod, itemNumber)));


<Select
  label="itemNumber"
  {(allProducts) // render all products not dependent on boolean
    .map((product, idx) => (
      <Mui.MenuItem
        key={`${product.itemNumber}_${idx}`}
        value={product.itemNumber}
        sx={{display: isItemVisibleInProductList(product.itemNumber) ? 'block' : 'none'}} // set display if true
        />
          {product.itemName}
      </Mui.MenuItem>
   ))}
   <ListSubheader sx={{ position: 'sticky', bottom: '0' }}>
     <Mui.Box sx={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}>
       <Mui.Button
         onClick={(event) => {
           setShowPreferredProducts((prev) => !prev);
        }}>
          {showPreferredProducts ? 'Show Preferred Products' : 'Show All Products'}
       </Mui.Button>
     </Mui.Box>
   </ListSubheader>
</Select>
```